# How to Truncate Spring Batch Job Tables in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I developed Spring Batch Jobs for processing hundreds of thousands flat files. This program long time worked properly. After, batch tables's row count and jobs's execution time increased.

I tried to truncate these tables. And I saw, I should drop some constraints for disabling. And then, I truncated tables at the last, I added constraints that dropped before. This code as shown below and works simultaneously with main program(File Processing).

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_STEP_EXECUTION] drop CONSTRAINT [JOB2_EXEC_STEP_FK]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION] drop CONSTRAINT [JOB2_INST_EXEC_FK]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS] drop CONSTRAINT [JOB2_EXEC_PARAMS_FK]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT] drop CONSTRAINT [JOB2_EXEC_CTX_FK]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT] drop CONSTRAINT [STEP2_EXEC_CTX_FK]


truncate table BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS
truncate table BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT
truncate table BATCH2_JOB_INSTANCE
truncate table BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION
truncate table BATCH2_STEP_EXECUTION
truncate table BATCH2_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [JOB2_EXEC_PARAMS_FK] FOREIGN KEY([JOB_EXECUTION_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION] ([JOB_EXECUTION_ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [JOB2_EXEC_PARAMS_FK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [JOB2_EXEC_CTX_FK] FOREIGN KEY([JOB_EXECUTION_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION] ([JOB_EXECUTION_ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT] CHECK CONSTRAINT [JOB2_EXEC_CTX_FK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [JOB2_INST_EXEC_FK] FOREIGN KEY([JOB_INSTANCE_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_INSTANCE] ([JOB_INSTANCE_ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION] CHECK CONSTRAINT [JOB2_INST_EXEC_FK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_STEP_EXECUTION]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [JOB2_EXEC_STEP_FK] FOREIGN KEY([JOB_EXECUTION_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION] ([JOB_EXECUTION_ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_STEP_EXECUTION] CHECK CONSTRAINT [JOB2_EXEC_STEP_FK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [STEP2_EXEC_CTX_FK] FOREIGN KEY([STEP_EXECUTION_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BATCH2_STEP_EXECUTION] ([STEP_EXECUTION_ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BATCH2_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT] CHECK CONSTRAINT [STEP2_EXEC_CTX_FK]
GO
```

Sometimes, I get this error

```
Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
'JOB2_EXEC_STEP_FK' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 27
There is already an object named 'JOB2_EXEC_CTX_FK' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 35
There is already an object named 'JOB2_INST_EXEC_FK' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 43
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "JOB2_EXEC_STEP_FK". The conflict occurred in database "db_name", table "dbo.BATCH2_JOB_EXECUTION", column 'JOB_EXECUTION_ID'.
Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line 47
Constraint 'JOB2_EXEC_STEP_FK' does not exist.
Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 47
Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.
```

How can I resolve this situation? Thank you very much.

Comment: "This code as shown below and works simultaneously with main program(File Processing).": if you truncate tables while a job is running then it is not a surprise to have issues like that. Have you considered truncating tables when no jobs are running?

Comment: I thought that but these jobs must run simultaneously. Maybe I check isolation levels. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I've discover a easiest way.

1. Using [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.javaetmoi.core/spring-batch-toolkit) library. The source code is public on github where you can see an example reading [this test](https://github.com/arey/spring-batch-toolkit/blob/master/src/test/java/com/javaetmoi/core/batch/tasklet/TestRemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet.java).
2. Manually: First be sure that your server is not running jobs. Then if you are using sql server you can run the [Official drop schema script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-sqlserver.sql) in your DB here. Or if you are using other db you can find an script for you [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core). Then you can recreate your schema in two ways:

a. Using official script to do it manually. Take a look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-sqlserver.sql) if you are using sql server or search your best option [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core).

b. Turning on `spring.batch.initialize-schema` property to `always`. Then restart your server to automatic spring batch schema recreation.

> spring.batch.initialize-schema=always

Comment: I think this is easiest way. I will use it. Thank you.

Comment: @Nico `spring.batch.initialize-schema=always` does not drop and recreate the schema for me? Any guess as to why?